# Android getting error using style parent

Tags: android

I am new user in this site and a newbie in android programming. Well, I come accros with following problem  in my app.

```
    Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
'SmoothProgressBar'.
```

I assume, the ploblem has occured when that style work

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.PullToRefresh" parent="SmoothProgressBar">
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/ptr_progress_bar_stroke_width</item>
</style>
```

I have `SmoothProgressBar` class. You can get source code [here](https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar). I am not using gradle, and didn't use maven. It is simple android project(If I can say simple). I googled and didn't fing simular case. Could you help me for resolve the problem.

I will edit this question, If you could not understand this situation

Answer (score 0):

pay attention to your parent declaration: in the very first example you can find declares style like this:
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium",
so, please be attentive ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have downloaded and connected with this project as a library GitHub to your Projects ? I think it can not find the resources because they do not know where to look. for [intellyj](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/creating-a-module-by-importing-existing-sources.html). Sorry for my English.